# How to add Instagram activity to UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am not able to find solution to add Instagram option to UIActivityViewController. Could anyone help. Thanks.

[image: Instagram activity in UIActivityViewController]

Comment: Post the code that you have tried.

Comment: I have tried code that add image to camera roll and then open Instagram app . But  I could'n able to find any code to that from UIActivityViewController.

Comment: have you find any solution about this? i am facing same issue don't know what to do.

Answer (score -2):

Use something like this:

```
@IBAction func shareOnIntagram(sender: UIButton) {

    let finalImage: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithView(photoView)
    let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1)
        let captionString = "caption"
        let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("instagram.ig")
        if imageData?.writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true) == false {

            return

        } else {

            let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)
            self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)
            self.documentController.delegate = self
            self.documentController.UTI = "com.instagram.photo"
            self.documentController.annotation = NSDictionary(object: captionString, forKey: "InstagramCaption")
            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
        }

    } else {
        print(" Instagram is not installed ")
    }
}
```

To make this code work, don't forget to add `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` in the UIViewController class.

Comment: I've already tried the code. It opens instagram app if installed , not present UIActivityViewController.

Comment: The answer is nowhere near to what is asked.